# How can I generate a CiviMail delivery & Click-thru report

Tags: civimail, civireport

I need to email a report to a person of a particular mass email that was sent from CiviMail. The person doesn’t have access to CiviCRM. How can I generate a CiviMail detailed delivery & Click-thru report from CiviReport and email using scheduled job? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use Mailing Summary report with filter as start and end date and configure it to send email via schedule job.